# Change page with mouse drag event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, mouse

I was wondering if it's possible to change a html page on a mouse drag event. I'm trying to allow a user to click and drag a white box to the left to change the page. The link to the project is here:

URL: http://davidpottrell.co.uk/library/phone/solent.html

As you can see, I'm trying to replicate how a mobile phone works. I've got the transitions close to correct. I'm now trying to create this mouse drag event.

If it is possible, does anyone know a resources or a tutorial as to how to accomplish the end result?

Comment: This note is OT, but why don't you use JavaScript for other functions too? Its weird, when the page reloads after clicking home.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/droppable/ this has a callback when the box was dropped. You can then redirect the user to the next page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about HTML5's `History API`? It allows to to change the current address without reloading the page.

So one way to do that might be to let AJAX fetch the contents of the next page, place it in the current page, then maybe a page slide transition or something, and then use `History API` to change the address.

Here's an article from Nettuts+ about it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/a-first-look-at-the-history-api/